# If $A$ exists and $m$ is in $A$, then $m$ exists

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I have a doubt.

Let us consider two statements (considered true):

1. There is a set $A$.
2. $m$ is an element of $A$.

Can we then ensure that $m$ also exists?

My question arose when reading the book Introduction to Modern Set Theory (third edition), by Judith Roitman:

Infinity Axiom: ∃x Ø ∈ x and x is inductive.

And soon after:

Proposition 28: ∃x x = Ø
(The Proposition is proved on the basis of the given Axiom)

Well... I think the Axiom already guarantees the existence of the set Ø.

I think so, but I'm very unsure about it.

Comment: Ok, Patrick Stevens. I will edit the question.

Comment: hi Paulo. can you give an example of the kind of situation you're thinking about? as written it's not entirely clear what you have in mind

Comment: Hi, Atticus. I just edited the question.

Comment: aha, I see now what you mean! yes, I'd agree it's a bit out of order. for the author to write $\exists X\ \varnothing\in X$ seems to presuppose the existence of an object $\varnothing$. I would just go ahead and read it as though Proposition 28 came first in the text

Comment: Hi, Atticus. But the Proposition is proved on the basis of the given Axiom.

Comment: I added this to the question.

Comment: hi Paulo. to me that seems most peculiar; personally I don't think it makes sense to formulate the axiom without already knowing that the object $\varnothing$ exists. so, in my personal opinion, it's a less a matter of the axiom guaranteeing the existence of $\varnothing$ than the axiom not really making sense without knowing the existence of $\varnothing$ already. but it's a bit of a pedantic point; if you want to circumvent the problem, note that you don't need the full strength of the axiom for Roitman's proof; all you need is the axiom $\exists x(x=x)$

Comment: Thanks, Atticus.

Comment: Existence is not a predicate. The statement “$m$ exists” is meaningless.

Answer (score 5):

If you can write "$m\in A$" then you already have a [term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Terms) $m$, and every term refers to something, so you're already assuming something exists. The statement "$m$ exists" isn't a meaningful proposition. (An existence sentence always introduces a new symbol, as in "there exists a natural number $x$ such that $x>10$".)

Comment: Ok, Karl. I understand.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, Roitman's approach is a bit weird...

The author does not state (as usual) an Empty Set Axiom: $\exists z \forall w (w \notin z)$, but introduce only a definition: $z=\emptyset \text { iff } \forall w (w \notin z)$.

Definitions do not "create" objects; thus, based on the definition, we cannot assert that there is **the** empty set, but we are only authorized to use the defined symbol as an abbreviation: e.g. $x \ne \emptyset$ means "$x$ is not empty".

In order to prove that some set exists, the author uses Infinity Axiom and Separation: Separation will be used **in conjunction with** an already existing set $X$ to "carve out" from it the empty set with the condition: $y \ne y$.

In details, the following instance of Separation must be used:

> $\exists z (w \in z \text { iff } w \in X \text  { and } (w \ne w) )$.

Due to the fact that condition $w \ne w$ is always false, there will be no $w$ that belongs to set $z$, i.e. $\forall w(w \ne z)$, i.e. $z$ is *empty*.

Now we may assert that there is a set that is empty; by Extensionality, if there is one it will be unique, and thus we can assert that **the** empty set exists.

The proof above applies Separation to the set $X$ whose existence is asserted by the Infinity Axiom: the "obscure point" is that the symbol $\emptyset$ is used in the statement of the axiom, and this seems not correct to me.

See also the post [Axiom of infinity and empty set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028727/axiom-of-infinity-and-empty-set); in order to avoid circularity, we have to state Infinity Axioms as follows:

> $∃X[∃z(z \in X \land ∀w(w \notin z)) \land ∀x( x \in X \to x \cup  \{ x \} \in X)]$.

---

In conclusion, if you want to follow Roitman's approach and avoid Empty Set Axiom, I think that it is better to avoid introducing a symbol (an individual constant) for it before having proved its existence.

A more streamlined approach will be: (i) state Infinity Axiom in the form above; (ii) use it to "feed" Separation in order to prove: $\exists z \forall w (w \notin z)$; (iii) use Extensionality to prove that two sets that are empty are equal.

Finally, having proved that there is a **unique** set that is empty, add to the language a new symbol for it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that, since the constant $\emptyset$ has been introduced by AOI (or other axiom),  we can infer $\emptyset = \emptyset$ by reflexivity. Therefore, we can infer by existential generalization (Intro $\exists$) that $\exists x: x=\emptyset$.